# How do I enable the zoom in/out option in a UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, zooming

How do I enable the zoom in/out option in a UIWebView?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it's the default feature of UIWebView. Use your fingers

Comment: so what is the answer for the question?

Comment: @dinesh you can see my answer. It's default feature of uiwebview pinch and zooming

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do it programmatically this is the only way I could find to accomplish it: (specify your own sizes if you wish, i was attempting to zoom out after typing into a form field)

```
UIScrollView *sv = [[webViewView subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
[sv zoomToRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, sv.contentSize.width, sv.contentSize.height) animated:YES];
```

Comment: As well with IOS5 you can now call webview.scrollview