# how to add pinch and zoom on a uiwebview - iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, pinchzoom

I know this question has been asked a couple of times before. I m trying to zoom in / out the uiwebview. How exactly do i do this? I tried setting  'webView.scalesPageToFit=YES;' but its not working.

I also tried this [How do I enable the zoom in/out option in a UIWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332261/iphone-uiwebview-zoom-in-out-option) but yet im not able to achieve the zoom in / out

Code

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[actorUrlArray objectAtIndex:_rowNumberInActivity]]];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:request];
webView.scalesPageToFit=YES;
```

what am i missing out here?

**NOTE** : I'm loading the iphone app on the ipad to check the app. Can that be a problem??

If its the meta tag problem. how do i set them? i tried this code.. but its not working.. i know nothing about javascript.. so im not sure whether this is correct or not..

```
NSString* js = 
@"var meta = document.createElement('meta'); \" \"meta.setAttribute( 'name', 'viewport' ); \" \"meta.setAttribute( 'content', 'width = device-width, initial-scale = 5.0, user-scalable = yes' ); \" \"document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta)";

[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: js];
```

Comment: Maybe the webpage you're showing explicitly disables user interactions using some WebKit-specific meta tags.

Comment: i set userinteraction enabvled as YES

Comment: Yes, **but that can be overridden by web code**.

Comment: Nothing, if it's overridden from the web page, all you can do is some ugly JavaScript injection to remove the harmful meta tag.

Comment: can you give me an example or some reference?

Comment: im assuming you are right.... im able to load other websites and zoom in and out...

Comment: please note down my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zooming in and out and Pinch are built in feature of UIWebView. You don't need to write any code to achieve that.

Comment: are u using device or simulator to test the pinch?

Answer (score 4):

just simply set the property.

> scalesPageToFit=YES

for any pinching and zooming to work on a UIWebView